# how to push to channel which is in list, without duplicate

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification

I am having trouble with PARSE Query "OR" in push notification sending

tldr: I want to be able to push notify all users who have one of 2 channels subscribed - with an OR - so each user (even if subscribed to 2 channels) only gets one notification.

e.g: I have the following channels:

`channel1`
`channel1_sub`

imagine a user who has subscribed to `channel1` and `channel1_sub` - I want to be able to  send a push, to either user who are subscribed to `channel1` OR `channel1_sub`

actually tried it with the following query (on POSTing the push):

```
{
    "where": {
        "channels": {
            "$in": [
                "channel1",
                "channel1_sub"
            ]
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "alert": "test"
    }
}
```

which results in 2 pushes - expected should be one - if user has subscribed both channels!

any help?

regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so i found a solution using the `$or` operator:

using the PHP-SDK from parse.com:

```
    $cat = array('channel1', 'channel_1_sub');
    $or_QUERY=array();

    for($z=0; $z<count($cat); $z++) {
        $query = ParseInstallation::query();
        $query->equalTo("channels", $cat[$z]);      
        $or_QUERY[]=$query;
    }

    $query_or = ParseQuery::orQueries($or_QUERY);

    $push_data = array(
      "where" => $query_or,
      "data" => $data
    );

    ParsePush::send($push_data);
```

wich actually results in following push payload:

```
{
  "where": {
    "channels": {
      "$or": [
        {
          "channels": "channel1"
        },
        {
          "channels": "channel1_sub"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "data": {
    "alert": "test"
  }
}
```

the result is that if a user is subscribed to both channels - only gets one push notification :)